# GetWindowLongPtr returns garbage

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I am developing a Win32 dialog box wrapper.

.h file

```
class dlg {
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProcTmp(HWND hwnd, 
                                       UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
    INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

    bool ismodal;
protected:
    HWND hwndDlg;
    int id;
public:
    virtual void oncreate(const widget &w) { }
    virtual void oncmd(const widget &w, int code, int idCntrl, HWND hwnd) { }
    virtual void onclose(const widget &w) { }
    dlg() { }
    dlg(int id);
    INT_PTR domodal(HWND hwndOwner = nullptr);
    widget domodeless(HWND hwndOwner = nullptr, int cmdshow = SW_SHOW);
};
```

.cpp file

```
INT_PTR dlg::DlgProcTmp(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    dlg *This;

    if (wm == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        This = (dlg *) lp;
        setwinlong(hwnd, DWLP_USER, This);
        This->oncreate(widget(hwnd));

        return TRUE;
    }
    if ((This = getwinlong<dlg *>(hwnd, DWLP_USER)) != nullptr)
        return This->DlgProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    return FALSE;
}
INT_PTR dlg::DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    this->hwndDlg = hwnd;
    switch (wm) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            this->oncmd(widget(hwnd), HIWORD(wp), LOWORD(wp), (HWND) lp);
            if (this->ismodal)
                EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wp));
            else
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return TRUE;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            this->onclose(widget(hwnd));
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

The dialog is created in `domodal` with a `DialogBoxParam` call. The last argument is the `this` pointer, which I then retrieve from the lparam of the `WM_INITDIALOG` message. To allow `this` to be used between different messages, I save `this` with the HWND in WM_INITDIALOG. However, whenever a message not WM_INITDIALOG arrives, and I get the `this` pointer with `GetWindowLongPtr`, it returns a garbage `dlg` class, whose vtable is corrupt. I use the vtable to call the correct handler function. As a result, my code crashes on the first line of the WM_COMMAND handler. Here is what the debugger shows as the value of `this`:

[image]

Why is GetWindowLongPtr returning garbage?

BTW, `getwinlong` is a wrapper for `GetWindowLongPtr`, and `setwinlong` is a wrapper for `SetWindowLongPtr`. Here are their implementations:

```
template <class TYPE> static TYPE getwinlong(HWND hwnd, int idx)
{
    return (TYPE) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, idx);
}
template <class TYPE> static void setwinlong(HWND hwnd, int idx, TYPE val)
{
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, idx, (LONG_PTR) val);
}
```

I have seen the numerous posts about how GetWindowLongPtr will fail on Win64, if you cast to LONG instead of LONG_PTR, like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131226-00/?p=2263. I believe that my problem is different.

**Edit**: @andlabs wanted the code that creates the dialog:

```
INT_PTR dlg::domodal(HWND hwndOwner)
{
    this->ismodal = true;
    return DialogBoxParam(gethinst(hwndOwner), 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), hwndOwner, dlg::DlgProcTmp, 
        (LPARAM) this);
}
```

Comment: Does the dialog template actually specify extra space for user data? Is the dialog itself using that data for its own purposes? There's always: [`SetProp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @theB You mean this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645398(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you post the code you use to create an instance of this dialog?

Comment: @andlabs Added that as an edit

Comment: Why all these downvotes?

Comment: Possible for naming convetions - class need start with uppercase - "Dlg"

Comment: What's `DLGPROC(dlg::DlgProcTmp)` for? If this doesn't compile without a cast/conversion, the you are possibly passing a function pointer with the wrong signature.

Comment: @oklas No, different programmers have different styles. Some choose to use camelCase, some PascalCase, some ALLCAPS. As long as it is readable, it should not matter

Comment: Are you shure that you set window long with good value? May be you set garbage, and than read that garbage back?

Comment: @oklas I am sure, because in WM_INITDIALOG, `This` (note the uppercase T) is dereferenced to call `oncreate`, but that works.

Comment: Do not say me abou styles - It is not my devote. You ask reason - I suppose for styling. May be not. I am here for help to you. Do not like comment say - I remove them.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What's wrong with that?

Comment: Try to add log output to yours setwinlong<> to sure. Errors is hide there - where we shure.

Comment: Nothing technically, it's just bad style to use a side effect. Browser posted before ready, sorry. :) You can write as `if( Bah* p = whatever )` using initialization instead of assignment.

Comment: Do some debugging. Observe or log the values that are used as args, are returned.

Comment: Yes, and I (and many others) write condition in reverse order to minificate ocurrance of assignment instead of comparision. `if( fun() == var )` instad of `if( var == fun() )` which will error whe one `=` is skipped.

Comment: Yes, SetWindowLongPtr is returning 0, but GetLastError() also gives 0. I also cleared the error number as per MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I wonder if the default dialog class reserves space for you, or if  you're using a custom window class that does that. Otherwise, oops. By the way, why not use `SetProp` and `GetProp`.

Comment: I use the default dialog window class @Cheersandhth.-Alf. Sorry for replying late, I was trying to research more information about custom dialog classes but could not find anything

Comment: Why are we arguing about style? Is this really constructive to figuring out this weird crash? Anyway I don't see anything immediately wrong, apart from your `WM_COMMAND` handler ending the dialog, but that probably isn't the problem. The vtable pointer is `0xCCCCCCCC`, which indicates an uninitialized variable. I'm not sure how this is even happening.

Comment: Shot in the dark: what is your `this` pointer and what pointer are you getting back instead?

Comment: I don't have my Petzold book available, but I think you'd need to use a custom window class for your approach. Instead, just use `SetProp` and `GetProp`. Or you can probably use the shell subclassing function, but I don't know how smart that function is wrt. dialog boxes.z

Comment: Uh... `DWLP_USER` is documented as being the same as `GWLP_USERDATA` except for dialog boxes. I'm using it just fine in my own code. The problem is elsewhere...

Comment: I think we need a [mcve].

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. My guess is the problem is elsewhere - something is randomly trashing memory. Try running your program with full pageheap enabled and see if it shows up anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pieced together the code that you've shown us, and was able to create a working sample:

dlg.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

class dlg {
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProcTmp(HWND hwnd, 
                                       UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
    INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

    bool ismodal;
protected:
    HWND hwndDlg;
    int id;
public:
    //virtual void oncreate(const widget &w) { }
    //virtual void oncmd(const widget &w, int code, int idCntrl, HWND hwnd) { }
    //virtual void onclose(const widget &w) { }
    dlg() { }
    dlg(int id) : id(id) { }
    INT_PTR domodal(HWND hwndOwner = nullptr);
    //widget domodeless(HWND hwndOwner = nullptr, int cmdshow = SW_SHOW);
};
```

dlg.cpp

```
#include "dlg.h"


template <class TYPE> static TYPE getwinlong(HWND hwnd, int idx)
{
    return (TYPE) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, idx);
}
template <class TYPE> static void setwinlong(HWND hwnd, int idx, TYPE val)
{
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, idx, (LONG_PTR) val);
}


INT_PTR dlg::DlgProcTmp(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    dlg *This;

    if (wm == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        This = (dlg *) lp;
        setwinlong(hwnd, DWLP_USER, This);
        //This->oncreate(widget(hwnd));

        return TRUE;
    }
    if ((This = getwinlong<dlg *>(hwnd, DWLP_USER)) != nullptr)
        return This->DlgProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    return FALSE;
}
INT_PTR dlg::DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    this->hwndDlg = hwnd;
    switch (wm) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            //this->oncmd(widget(hwnd), HIWORD(wp), LOWORD(wp), (HWND) lp);
            if (this->ismodal)
                EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wp));
            else
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return TRUE;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

INT_PTR dlg::domodal(HWND hwndOwner)
{
    this->ismodal = true;
    return DialogBoxParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), hwndOwner, dlg::DlgProcTmp, 
        (LPARAM) this);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    dlg myDialog(IDD_DIALOG);
    myDialog.domodal();

    return 0;
}
```

---

You'll notice that there's a fair bit of the code that has been commented out—in particular, the declarations for and calls to the virtual message-handling functions (`onXXX`) have been omitted. I did this because I didn't have the definition for the `widget` type, and I didn't think it was germane to your actual problem.

Turns out it must be, since the code works fine so long as those virtual message-handling functions are not called.

I then added in a stub class for `widget` as follows:

```
class widget
{
public:
   widget(HWND hWnd)
      : m_hWnd(hWnd)
   { }

   HWND m_hWnd;
};
```

and uncommented the `oncmd` function as well as the call to it in the `WM_COMMAND` handler. Again, the code compiles and works correctly. So I have no idea what problem you're experiencing. It must be in the `widget` class or some other code you have not shown to us.

There is at least one tweak I would make to the code. Assign the `hwndDlg` member variable inside of the `DlgProcTemp` function, rather than waiting until the `DlgProc` function. So, do this:

```
INT_PTR dlg::DlgProcTmp(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    dlg *This;

    if (wm == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        This = (dlg *) lp;
        setwinlong(hwnd, DWLP_USER, This);
        This->hwndDlg = hwnd;
        This->oncreate(widget(hwnd));

        return TRUE;
    }
    if ((This = getwinlong<dlg *>(hwnd, DWLP_USER)) != nullptr)
        return This->DlgProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    return FALSE;
}
INT_PTR dlg::DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (wm) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            this->oncmd(widget(hwnd), HIWORD(wp), LOWORD(wp), (HWND) lp);
            if (this->ismodal)
                EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wp));
            else
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return TRUE;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Also strongly consider [using C++-style casts in preference to C-style casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

If you are still having a problem getting the code to work, you will have to edit into your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), just like I have done here.